Node.js v22.12 ends immediately without any output when running a file on Windows
I recently upgraded Node.js on my Windows machine to version v22.12, and now any script I run from a file exits immediately without displaying any output. For example:
> node test.js
# (no output, program finishes instantly)

Here is a minimal example of test.js (though the content seems irrelevant; even a single console.log() fails to produce output):
console.log("Hello from Node.js");
setInterval(() => {
  console.log("Still running...");
}, 2000);

Key observations:

If I run the same code inline using -e, it does work:
node -e "console.log('Hello from inline'); setInterval(() => {console.log('Still running inline...');}, 3000)"


If I downgrade Node.js to v20.18, the file-based execution works as expected, producing output as normal.

Before upgrading to v22.12, everything worked correctly on the same machine.

After reverting to v20.18, it started working again without changing any other settings.


Was there a change in Node.js v22.12 that affects how scripts should be started on Windows, or could there be a specific configuration or security policy on my Windows PC that might cause this behavior? Has anyone else encountered this issue or found a workaround?
For now, I'm staying on v20.18 since it resolves the problem, but I'd prefer to upgrade if there's a known fix or setting adjustment.

can not duplicate - what about node 23.x

Might be a dumb question, but are you sure you are executing the correct file (ie are you in the correct directory) and is the file saved to disk? Otherwise I don't see any possibility the shown script would not produce any output, regardless of the version of node ...

There were no such changes in 22, and this kind of breaking changes would be impossible for node. The problem is not reproducible. As noted, that a wrong script is executed would be a reasonable explanation. Any problem with file access or encoding should result in a meaningful error. You can try type test.js && node test.js to make sure.  Use where node to check which installation is used. You can also try fnm to switch versions and see if a problem is specific to your current node installation, though I'm unaware of a scenario under which this could be possible.
